# How to I manage Azure "files" from GUI and command line?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I'm confused about the difference between "files" and other objects in Azure storage. I understand how to upload a file to a share using the Azure web console and command line, but in the [Azure Storage Explorer](http://storageexplorer.com) I don't see either of these, but only see "blobs" and though I can upload "files" there using the explorer, I can't upload to or see any of my "file" "shares".

Is there a way to browse and manage "files" and "shares" using Azure Storage Explorer, or some other client or CLI tool (on OS X)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the different services. Azure Storage is... the "umbrella" service that consists of some services - **Queues** (obvious :)), **Tables** (kind of a noSQL table storage), **Blobs** (binary large objects, from text files to multimedia) and **Files** (the service that implements the file shares that may be connected to the Virtual Machine, for example, as a file share).

They are different services that may be used from the Azure Storage Explorer, but it depends on what you want to use and/or implement. If you need to put just files, you may use blobs. If you need to attach the storage as a file share to the VM, then the Files service is what you need. [Good comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24880430/azure-blob-storage-vs-file-service).

I am not sure if you can manage Files with the Azure Storage Explorer (UPD: checked - do not), but something like [CloudXplorer](http://clumsyleaf.com/products/cloudxplorer) is able to do that.

Comment: CloudXplorer is Windows only, I think.

Comment: So if the goal is to upload a file for use in, say, Azure machine learning (e.g., a data source or wiped code resource) Blobs are the intended tool?

Comment: For machine learning service, [i see that](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/machine-learning-import-data-from-online-sources/) azure files is not supported as a data source, but azure blobs are. So, if that is the scenario, i would go with the blobs.

Comment: Azure storage feels like its in transition (these distinctions are a bit confusing from a user point of view, and some services and tools seem to support Blobs and Files without much distinction, will others seem to support only Blobs). Is there a white paper or roadmap that give a hint of where this is going.

Comment: One of the best Azure whitepapers i saw were written by [David Chappell](http://davidchappellopinari.blogspot.ru).  But his whitepaper on Storage is quite old (but i can't say that it is really outdated). So, the most up-to-date whitepaper is on the [official documentation hub](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-introduction/) where you may see the differences in the services. Regarding names - yes, may be confusing.

Comment: Regarding roadmap - you may go to the [official MSFT cloud platform roadmap](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/roadmap/) but it is not go very deep into the details.

Comment: (I assume all this means there's no way to use standard tools — e.g., to `git push` code bundles for example — to sync files to Azure.)

Comment: This isn't the place for a discussion. I suggest you start a Chat.

Answer (score 1):

You can browse and add/edit/delete files in Azure File Shares similar to how you would any other file share after mounting. You can refer to these two articles on how to do so:

- [Mount Azure File Share in Windows](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files/#mount-the-file-share)
- [Mount Azure File Share in Linux](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-how-to-use-files-linux/#mount-the-file-share)

Alternatively, you can use CLI or PowerShell, see examples below:

- [PowerShell example](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/storage-powershell-getting-started/blob/master/AzureFiles.ps1)
- [CLI example](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/storage-cli-getting-started/blob/master/Bash%20Scripts/AzureFiles.sh)